# Errors when creating new columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to count occurrences of user ids (`id`) in a dataframe, by creating a new column called `n_occurrences`. It always results in a KeyError and I'm unsure why. In the same method, I create a new column for elapsed time (`elapsed_time`) which works without errors.

code sample:

```py
import pandas as pd

class Clean_Data:
    def __init__(self, data): #data is path to csv
        self.make_df(data)
        self.df

    def make_df(self,data):
        data_raw = pd.read_csv(data,header=0,nrows=100)
        #do stuff that returns valid dataframe, cleans up unwanted data
        self.df = data_raw
        return self.df #df with shape 100 rows, 27 cols

    def analyze_the_data(self):
        self.df['n_occurrences'] = self.df.groupby(['id','time']).transform('count') 
        # ^ fails as well if I try with or without the line 'self.df['n_Occurrences']'
        # has error ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 25, placement implies 1

        self.df['time_elapsed'] = (self.df['time']-self.df['time'].shift()) # works--creates time_elapsed col
        print(self.df.shape) #shows dataframe shape of 100 rows, 28 cols 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Clean_Data(r'/path/to.csv')
    c.analyze_the_data()
```

Dataframe (should) change to 63 rows, 28 cols after the `groupby` line. There are upwards of 50,000 lines so I'm just using 100 to save on time until everything is working.

output of error line:

```py
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 25, placement implies 1
```

why does it fail when I create the `n_occurrences` col but not when i do the `time_elapsed` col?

Comment: Calling just `self.df['n_occurrences']` results in key error as that column doesn't exist

Comment: Oh. For some reason I assumed that it would just coerce the column into existence, but apparently not. That doesn't explain why it also fails on the line below, however.

Comment: it's called in the `__init__` func

Comment: Saw it. My bad.

Comment: can you post the full error again after removing the `self.df['n_occurrences'] #results in key error` line? I suspect the error comes from the fact that the number of rows are different after you `groupby` in the second line.

Comment: I made the edit, and will put it here as well: `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 25, placement implies 1`

Comment: can you also post an example of how the `df` looks like, and how it looks like after `groupby('..').transform('count')`

Comment: if you mean by shape,I added in that it should be 63x28, (which would then change to 63x29 after `time_elapsed` is created.